# Adding two UIBarButtomItems with image programmatically

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to use following code in my viewDidLoad method to add two UIBarButtonItems to the left side of the navigation bar, but only the second button is shown:

```
//nav bar buttons


UIView* leftButtonView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];

UIButton* leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
leftButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
leftButton.frame = leftButtonView.frame;
[leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toTop"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
leftButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; //Your desired color.
leftButton.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
leftButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toTop:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


UIView* leftButtonView2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 0, 40, 40)];
UIButton* leftButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
leftButton2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
leftButton2.frame = leftButtonView.frame;
[leftButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toSectionTop"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftButton2 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
leftButton2.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; //Your desired color.
leftButton2.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
leftButton2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
[leftButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(toTop:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



[leftButtonView addSubview:leftButton];
[leftButtonView2 addSubview:leftButton2];

UIBarButtonItem* leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:leftButtonView];
UIBarButtonItem* leftBarButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:leftButtonView2];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton2;
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the same property twice so the second setting replaces the first. Try:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[ leftBarButton, leftBarButton2 ];
```

Note this is setting leftBarButtonItem**s**, which takes an array of bar buttons.

Also, you shouldn't need the container views, they add no value. Buttons are views so you can use them directly. Setting the frame origin of the view may also cause you issues.